# Law of maintaining energy flow

Tags: perpetual-motion

Wouldn't machine that can create constant flows of energy be possible if we eliminate mechanically created energy losses?

The time limitation of resources, the magnet half-life time duration isn't here a issue, I'm talking about machine that could run itself and give-spare energy.
Machine could be serviced every couple off year's. The magnets have huge time energy, like the gravity... because they energy is constantly present in the space throughout time. Constant stability in the source off energy is only logical source type, the gravitation on this planet and magnetic influence on matter in that gravitation is most practical to be a new clean source off energy.
There should be a way to create constant flow off energy with quite precise control of magnetic field?
Weight of a rotor could be eliminated on gravity level? Is there way to eliminate gravitational force and is there a formula for it?
Mechanically created losses are also magnetic interaction with iron because magnetization of iron is limited to 2.25T, polling forse of interction magnet with iron is huge mechanical energy loss, because that issue we need huge input energy. So I wonder is there a way to go around the iron and remove it from classical machines for creating energy?

Comment: I'm not sure what answers you expect to get - if someone on this forum had thought of a way to create free energy (or an antigravity effect, as per your other question), why would they reveal it right here, right now?

Comment: Logical point if view...yes.

Comment: But why they wouldn't discussed about it? At least, we can make discussion why isn't possible. I ask for opinions, not answers. Wan't talk about some nature laws

Comment: I don't want to turn this into some sort of edit war, but I agree with @QMechanic's tag edits.

Comment: OK,thanks for the time, there isn't reason for something like that, thx @QMechanic's for advice and edit, I,l respect yours decision guys, but if someone could menage to find time for discussion because this is subject off huge interest for me. Thanks

Comment: There is such thing as magnetic energy and, like all other forms of energy,  it can be converted into other forms of energy. You might want to read up on [magnetic reconnection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reconnection). That said, $E_{out}\leq E_{in}$ by [1st law of thermodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics), there is no free lunch.

Comment: Yes, I know all electric laws writed in book's, but there is little bit more... most of the laws are made for mechanical forms of trasfering energy from form to form, that rules cannot be applied on machine that use gravitational energy.

Answer (score 2):

It is a tautological statement to say that perpetual motion is possible if there is no dissipation of energy.

But even a device that, once set in motion, truly maintains a perpetual motion could not provide a source of energy - if you extract energy from the device to use it, then its energy content is diminished, since energy is conserved. So even a true perpetually moving device is not useful as an energy source (though, being able to gain useable energy without dissipative or other losses would be an improvement).

Comment: My point of view is quite different, unorthodox concerning the creating energy. Who say that iron must be in any device that at the moment we use to create el.energy, classic generator. Additionally what happen if we set two opposite ring magnet poles each on other and set weight on them, then spin that weight, we get additional time energy that could be controlled in couple ways... in main - if we produce in same amount off time two different effect, with certainty we can conclude that one of them have little difernet amount off energy and form of energy that definitely could be controlled?

Comment: What if there is a way to create output energy higher that input? Additionally' this is a statement: if is possible to control matter motion in space (that have or doesn't not have specific gravity (variable X, vacuum or earth gravity)) we control time in that space. Magnets have energy that is invisible with eye but produce energy even in state off calm position, we know to create el.energy with change of magnetic induction in copper, but we have not try to eliminate loses in proces off creating that energy.

Comment: Could you explain @ACuriousMind, with what you disagreed in my question? And could you back up that claims.